# What is an alternative to using strings for action and controller names in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there an alternative method to using strings for action and controler names as string?

for example is there any method similar to

```
typeOf(MyWebSite.Controllers.ControllerZ.Action01).Name
typeOf(MyWebSite.Controllers.ControllerZ).Name
```

being used? or is there a way to just use the Controller method name as such : `MyWebSite.Controllers.ControllerZ.Action01` as a parameter so there is no need to also hardcode a string for Controller name that is now deriveable from Action?

Forexample consider Html.BeginForm("actionname","controllername"), how do we get rid of hardcoded strings in that?

Comment: Please can you let us know what the problem is that you're facing

Comment: Do you mean to achive something like: @Url.Action<HomeController>(x => x.Index) and this to generate url t0 HomeController -> Index action method?

Comment: @Luke want to use strongly typed redeemed than hard doing strings. I am sure I can't be the first person who doesn't like hardicoding strings instead of using strong typing

Comment: One of the solutions is T4MVC - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371103/magic-strings-in-asp-net-mvc/8371138#8371138.

Comment: @media, what does it have to do with a problem? Did you even read it?

Comment: C# 6 has nameof

Comment: @Atomosk, that won't work as easily as it should - `nameof` will include `Controller` in the name of controller, which helpers do not accept.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216413/what-is-the-syntax-for-a-strongly-typed-actionlink-in-mvc-4-with-mvc-4-futures

Comment: MVC magic name strings are going to bite you on this. The class/type name does not line up with what the helpers and even controller DI expects (x-'controller').